# How to keep the chrome browser open with Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to open google page with a python code in visual studio editor using the following code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

#browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
Path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(Path)
browser.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

My problem is the chrome window it opens for 2 or 3 secondes and it close. Did some one face this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The default framework of ***visual studio editor*** would close the Chrome browser, per say any browser client after the last line of your program gets executed.

Hence, once the line of code:

```
browser.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

gets executed, the Chrome browser is *CLOSED*. This is the expected behavior.

---

Incase you like to keep the Chrome browser *OPEN* even after the last line of your program gets executed, you can pass the experimental option ***`detach`*** as *`true`* as follows:

> [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) compatible code

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

Comment: Even by adding this option it's not working. the chrome closes after 2 or 3 secondes max.